# Express Js Router methods

Tags: node.js, express, express-router

I am new to expressjs and nodejs .I have found few methods in  express router using visual studio code vs intellisense .For few of them i didn't found any documentation regarding below methods ,how exactly it can be used in real world like `get,post,put,patch` .So i thought to ask in stackoverflow.It might help everyone who are looking similar to this

```
const router = express.Router()
router.options
router.head
router.checkout
router.connect
router.copy
router.lock
router.merge
router.mkactivity
router.mkcol
router.move
router.'m-search'
router.notify
router.propfind
router.proppatch
router.purge
router.report
router.search
router.subscribe
router.trace
router.unlock
router.unsubscribe
router.apply
router.bind
router.arguments
router.caller
router.call
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#routing-methods

#### Express Routing methods

Express supports the following routing methods corresponding to the HTTP methods of the same names:

`checkout copy delete get head lock merge mkactivity mkcol move m-search notify options patch post purge put report search subscribe trace unlock unsubscribe`

The API documentation has explicit entries only for the most popular HTTP methods `app.get(), app.post(), app.put(),` and `app.delete()`. However, the other methods listed above work in exactly the same way.